# Unable to use collectionGroup query in AngularFirestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3, angularfire2

I am using AngularFirestore and Ionic 3. I want to use the collectionGroup query feature of Firebase but I am not getting this option either by importing AngularFirestore or doing `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

`this.afs.collectionGroup()` is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AngularFire2 documentation shows how to [use Collection Group Queries](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#collection-group-queries).

If that doesn't work for you, ensure you're using [AngularFire2 version 5.2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.2.0) or later.